# MySQL query to check missing many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three MySQL tables as below:

```
 CREATE TABLE  students (
  StudentName VARCHAR(255),   
  StudentID VARCHAR(255) 
  );

 CREATE TABLE  courses (
  CourseName VARCHAR(255),   
  CourseID VARCHAR(255) 
  );

CREATE TABLE  participation (
 CourseID VARCHAR(255),   
 StudentID VARCHAR(255) 
 );

INSERT INTO students
 VALUES ('Biplab',  '04CS9501'),
       ('Amit',  '05CS3001'),
       ('Rahul',  '05CS3003'),
       ('Divya',  '05CS3004'),
       ('Praveen',  '05CS3005');


INSERT INTO courses
 VALUES ('Business and Science',  'B3D'),
        ('Economics',  'B3B'),
        ('Business and Laws',  '63O1'),
        ('Economics and Laws',  '63K1'),
        ('Economics and Science',  'B3E');

  INSERT INTO participation 
    VALUES ('B3D',  '04CS9501'),
    ('B3D',  '05CS300'),
    ('B3D',  '05CS3003'),
    ('B3B',  '05CS3003'),
    ('B3B',  '05CS3004'),
    ('63O1',  '04CS9501'),
    ('63O1',  '05CS3004'),
    ('63K1',  '05CS3001'),
    ('63K1',  '05CS3003'),
    ('63K1',  '05CS3004');
```

Working on the assumption that every student must take a course and every course must have student participation, I would like to test the integrity of the data by being able to identify the courses which do not have students or students that do not have course participation. In this case, student "Praveen" and course "Economics and Science".

How would such a query be constructed?

Comment: Tip of today: Use integer data type for the id columns! And declare them as primary keys! Have another column for you short names.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:sqlite]? It seems like you don't use SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution to get all courses without `participation`:

```
-- to get all empty courses using "WHERE NOT ... IN ..."
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE NOT CourseID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM participation)

-- or using "LEFT JOIN"
SELECT c.*
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN participation p ON c.CourseID = p.CourseID
WHERE p.StudentID IS NULL
```

... and the following solution to get the students without `participation`:

```
-- to get all students wihtout participation using "WHERE NOT ... IN ..."
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE NOT StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID FROM participation)

-- or using "LEFT JOIN"
SELECT s.*
FROM students s LEFT JOIN participation p ON s.StudentID = p.StudentID 
WHERE p.CourseID IS NULL
```

You can also use a `LEFT JOIN` to get the expected records. Additionaly you can use `UNION ALL` and a additional column to get all records with one query:

```
SELECT 'Student' AS type, s.StudentID AS 'ID', s.StudentName AS 'Name' 
FROM students s LEFT JOIN participation p ON s.StudentID = p.StudentID 
WHERE p.CourseID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Course' AS type, c.CourseID, c.CourseName 
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN participation p ON c.CourseID = p.CourseID
WHERE p.StudentID IS NULL

ORDER BY type, Name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea27cb584fb5d3508004d201bfd8ea82)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery with `NOT EXISTS` to check for students with no record in the `participation` table.

```
SELECT *
       FROM students s
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM participation p
                                WHERE p.studentid = s.studentid);
```

And analogous for the courses.